# Transform scale an html element and detransform with a javascript setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, css

I have this copy icon I want to transform scale when i click and detransform after 3 seconds.
Here is the HTML for the icon:-

```
   <span class="customURL-copy copy">
      <i class="far fa-clone"></i>
   </span>
```

I decided that I will add a class of "copy-animation" to the  tag when clicked like so:-

```
const copyIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".copy"); //thr are multiple,fr example sake I have demonstrated only one

  copyIcons.forEach((icon)=>{
   icon.addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
     const child =  event.target.childNodes[1]; //the <i> tag
     child.classList.add("copy-animation");
     setTimeout(function(){
      child.classList.remove("copy-animation");
     console.log(child.classList);
     },3000)
   })
 })
```

The CSS code for class "copy-animation" is as below -

```
.copy-animation{
  transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
}
```

The event listener successfully adds the ".copy-animation" class to the icon tag and the icon scales.Inside the setTimeout function which runs 3 seconds after the event listener is fired.I am removing the ".copy-animation" class to supposidly scale back the icon.But that is not happening.The icon remains scaled even after removing the ".copy-animation" class successfully.
The problem is that the icon is not scaling down even after the successful removal of the ".copy-animation" class.
Please help me out with this.
Any kind of help is really appriciated.THANK YOU

Comment: Use `const child =  event.target;` instead. Clicking the span will also click the `<i>` and `.target` is therefore the `<i>` already. Use `document.querySelectorAll(".copy i")` to be sure though, since the span is like a pixel taller than the `<i>`. (the lesson here is to always do basic debugging first: console.log() *everything*, to make sure variables contain what you think they contain)

Comment: When I apply the transform scale to it.It wont scale because it is a span.I must scale the icon itself.So selecting that is approriate